# Finding the optimal trajectory of a airplane? Similar to the Brachistochrone problem.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My professor gave me the following problem for some extra credit. I have been working on it for quite some time now but with little to no advances. Any advice or hints on how to solve the problem?

> Suppose that an airplane departs from the point $(0,0)$ located due west of its intended destination airport at $(0,a)$. The plane travels with constant speed $v_0$ relative to the wind, which is blowing due north with constant speed $\omega$.
>
> - Find the fastest route. That is, find the trajectory $y = g(x)$, $g(a) = 0$, $g(0) = 0$, such that it takes the shortest time to reach the airport.
> - Find the shortest time.

My suspicion is that the fastest route is a straight line to the other airport, but I have no proof. Here is my unsuccessful attempt at a very non-rigorous proof should it give you a idea of what I have already done:

> $v_x = v_0\cos(\theta(x))$ and $v_y = v_0\sin(\theta(x)) + \omega$
>
> $\implies T = \int_0^a \frac{dx}{v_0\cos(\theta(x))}$
>
> $\implies v_0T = \int_0^a\sec(\theta(x))dx$
>
> $\int_0^a \frac{v_y}{v_x}dx = 0$
>
> $\implies \int_0^a \frac{v_0\sin(\theta(x)) + \omega}{v_0 \cos(\theta(x))} = 0$
>
> $\implies \int_0^a tan(\theta(x)) + \frac{\omega}{v_0}\int_0^a\sec(\theta(x))dx = 0$
>
> $\implies T = \frac{-1}{\omega}\int_0^a f(x)dx$ where $f(x) \in (-\infty, \infty)$

The problem with the above problem is this implies there can be negative time, so I know I screwed up somewhere along the line. Anyway, I am going to tag Differential Equations in this since that is the class I am taking.